# Prevent merge cell to split across pages

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have generated an Excel document with jxls and POI. Now POI has merged cell, half data is in page 1 & other half of merged cell in page 2. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't. That's a disadvantage of Excel. Excel does not provide a "keep merged cells on one page" feature. One need to set an explicit page break above of the row which shall the first on the new page.

Apache POI provides [Sheet.setRowBreak](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setRowBreak-int-) to do so.

So you need to know what row is the first one having the merged cells split into two pages. Then set row break to the row above.

For example if first row index of the rows having the merged cells split into two pages is 25, then:

```
...
Sheet sheet ...
...
sheet.setRowBreak(24);
...
```

Of course this only can be used if the row positions on the page are  static or if one knows how many rows fit to one page. I don't know any more dynamic solution.

---

Same is if merged columns split over two pages. Then manually set a column break is needed.

Apache POI provides [Sheet.setColumnBreak](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnBreak-int-) to do so.

Of course this has same disadvantages as manually row break has.

Comment: Many many Thanks, was thinking of similar approach only, but just want to get some idea from Stack overflow experts...